# IF statement in a PHP script

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a question about a If-statement that is really making me crazy. 
It seems that I didn't find a right solution. Please let me explain the situation. 
There are **4 possible situations**.

1. Without a film
2. Without a picture
3. Without a film but with a picture
4. without a picture but with a film

*A little bit more information but maybe not necessary.* 
The fields film and pictures are fields in a database. With a PHP script, i'm checking if a field is filled with something. With this information i'm going to build my page. In some case there will be no place for a picture, or for a movie for example. I hope you understand what i'm telling.

**This is my code**

```
<?php
    class Artikel{
public function printWholeArticle()
        {
            include ('connection.php');
            $sSql = "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datum) as unixDatum, titel, artikel, id, image, video FROM tblArtikels WHERE id = '" . $this->m_sKey."'"; 
            $res = $mysqli -> query($sSql);
            return ($res);
        }
}


$key = $_GET['id']; // I get the key from the url
$oNieuwsArtikel = new Artikel();
$oNieuwsArtikel -> Key = $key;
$vAllNieuwsArtikel = $oNieuwsArtikel -> printWholeArticle();

$artikel = $vAllNieuwsArtikel -> fetch_assoc();


// just a part of my if statement, to let you guys know how I print the data to the screen
if ($artikel['image'] == "")
            {
                echo "<div class='datum'>" . "<div class='day'>" . date('d', $artikel['unixDatum']) . "</div>" . "<div class='month'>" . "/" . date('m',                            $artikel['unixDatum']) . "</div>" . "<div class='year'>" . date('Y', $artikel['unixDatum']) . "</div>" . "</div>";
            echo "<p>" . "<div class='content_wrap_page'>" .  "<div class='artikel_page'>" 
            . "<h1>" . $artikel['titel'] ."</h1>" . $artikel['artikel'] . "</div>" . "</div>" . "</p>";
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (empty($artikel['video']))
{
    // no film code

    if (!empty($artikel['image']))
    {
        // no film but with picture code
    }
}
else if (empty($artikel['image']))
{
    // no picture code

    if (!empty($artikel['video']))
    {
        // no picture but with film code
    }
}
```

Where $film and $picture are set to the value retrieved from the database query.

Comment: I can not make variables because the values are in a while loop. (see my code)

Comment: The above would work, you just needed to change the vars to point to the array values you wanted to check.